# Disable certain settings if user hasn't done an in-app purchase

Tags: android, google-play

There are certain settings in my app that I don't want to be enabled unless the user has purchased an in-app purchase. How do I go about doing that?

As far as the settings go I'm just using a PreferenceFragment as follows:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FragmentSettings extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the official example given by android for implementing in-app purchases.

[Implementing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

Now how you do that is you can save the status of purchase in a static Boolean. on app start you can set this Boolean from preferences, if that boolean is true you give access to locked content. if false, you can queryinventory with IabHelper. if it returns that the user has bought the product you can set it to true also save in preferences, else set it to false and lock the content. now user will have to buy the product then you can update the status.

this also works in case if user has uninstalled the app and reinstalled it again.by doing a query of inventory on the start you can automatically unlock the content on re-install.
Hopes it gives you idea.